# Why is my table search 'clear' function script not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, search

I am using javascript to search a html-table using two methods: a category (select option drop-down) and search bar (text input).

I was using the following script and it functioned fine in chrome, but not ie:

```
 function _filter(row) {
        var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        var category = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
        var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : ((filter === '' || category.includes(filter)) && 'table-row');
    }
```

So I changed `includes` to `indexOf` as below.

```
function _filter(row) {
        var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        var category = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
        var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : ((filter === '' || category.indexOf(filter)) && 'table-row');
```

This works, but when I backspace letters or select clear, the table returns all rows of the full table, disregarding the current 'category' that is selected. This did not happen when using contains. It seems to no longer regard the getElementsByTagName [0] array - which was supposed to mean only the first column was searched (which lists the categories) and not the actual content of the table. 
Can anyone help please?
Thanks!

Comment: `includes` is not supported in IE.

Comment: One thing. `category.indexOf(filter)` should be `category.indexOf(filter) !== -1`. As indexOf can return `0` which will be considered `false`. See 'Checking occurrences' section of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Yup, so I changed to indexOf - but now the clear/backspace is not limiting to the category chosen in the select option

Comment: Please re-read Umair's comment.

Comment: Where is `_input` defined as used in `val = _input.value.toLowerCase();`

Comment: @UmairKhan thanks Umair that completely fixed it! Just need to be defined as !== -1 ... you are amazing!

Comment: @UmairKhan, I suggest you post the suggestion as an answer. So that Nic can accept your suggestion as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of questions. thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT and Umair, I have accepted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by @Deepak-MSFT.

Putting the comment that helped, as answer.

> One thing.
>
> `category.indexOf(filter)` should be `category.indexOf(filter) !== -1`.
>
> As `indexOf` can return `0` which will be considered `false`.
>
> See 'Checking occurrences' section of
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf